# I completely removed libsqlite3-0 and everything essential was removed. How do I restore ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04

I just removed sqlite3 and everything was removed. Everything!  I can log into a command line. Can I restore from that?

edit

When I reboot I get the message

```
could not write bytes: Broken pipe
```

I must hit Ctrl+Alt+F2 to get a login shell.  If I log in and try

```
sudo apt-get sqlite3 --fix-broken
```

I get

```
Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
```

## Update

I don't have a network connection when I log back in. I tried

sudo service network-manager restart

But that doesn't work. I can't get an ipaddress from my router

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: This isn't a question, and original had swear words.

Comment: The original was "ubuntu just removed everyting".  But that was an unacceptable question.  Out of complete frustration on my cell phone I wrote "Ubuntu just removed everything...every f****ing thing" thinking there was no way that that would be an acceptable question in the stack system and it would reject that too.  However it didn't.

Comment: I would suggest going through the tour http://askubuntu.com/tour It has code of conduct, and samples of how to write a question. Right now you do not have a question, and no one can derive any information from what you have posted. Not to be mean, but how could anyone help you, or know where to start?

Comment: I'll alter the question.

Comment: Might be better to just delete and do a new one, to get rid of downvotes

Comment: What command did you use to remove sqlite3? Can you be more specific about what you mean by "everything"? Thanks.

Comment: I used synaptic to remove it.  I clicked the option to completely remove sqlite3.  When I say "everything" I mean firefox, chorme, rhythmbox, gnome, etc...Everything.  I've never had this happen.  I'm sure nautalis was in there too.  When I reboot I have to hit Ctrl+Alt F1 to get a command line.  I've tried sudo apt-get to reinstall but I get errors also.

Comment: You might want to include the detail that this is a remote computer, you are tunneling into. broken pipe means the tunnel failed. could not resolve, probably happend first, or before the broken pipe. i was able to resolve us.archive.ubuntu.com soo... are you behind a proxy? give us all the information you can, about the set up, and what you are trying to do....wait, are you rebooting a remote shell then expecting to still issue commands???

Comment: This is not a remote computer.  It is my laptop that I use everyday.

Comment: Can you boot to command line? If so reinstall entire desktop. When uninstalling in synaptic did you look at the long list it was uninstalling? Many applications use sqlite for their data. If you cannot boot to command line you may chroot into system or do a "dirty" install to reinstall system but keep your data (reinstall withour reformat / partition). But that dirty install will still overwrite any settings back to defaults.

Comment: I am now talking from my linux computer.  I was able to boot to command line.  I had to reconfigure the network to get internet access and I had to reinstall ubuntu-desktop.  I foolishly did not look over the list that was being uninstalled.  I would have thought a bigger warning would've came up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, what happened was I marked libsqlite3-0 for complete removal in synaptic.  Big mistake!  This will remove a lot of essential programs (python, nautilus, unity, etc.).  I was panicking as icons were suddenly disappearing from my menu bar.

Upon reboot I got the message

```
could not write bytes: Broken pipe
```

and no user interface.

## What I did to fix this

After booting in and no user interface, I hit ctrl+alt+f1 to give me a command shell.  After logging in with my user name and password I tried to use apt-get to repair the broken sqlite packages but my networking was not functional.  So I plugged in my Ethernet cord and had to go to my network interfaces configuration to get my Ethernet to work.

I ran the command

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

and added the lines

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

then ran

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

as described here http://blog.poorakkashyap.com/2012/solved-error-unknown-interface-eth0eth0-on-ubuntu/

now my networking was working and I had internet access

so I then ran

```
sudo apt-get install sqlite3 --fix-missing
```

I let this run and reinstall everything.  I then tried to start my desktop by running

```
startx
```

My desktop didn't start.  I don't remember the specific error that I got.

I then ran

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

that reinstalled everything back.

Everything seems to be back to normal and I didn't have to completely reinstall ubuntu.  I guess the big take away from this is that if you happen to remove an essential package from ubuntu know that you can go to a command line by pressing ctrl+alt+f1 (or any of the function keys), ensure you have internet access, and use apt-get to repair the broken packages.